# Why isn't EnableCorsAttribute working for me?

Tags: security, asp.net-web-api, cors, asp.net-web-api2

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config, bool enableDiagnostics = true)
    {
        config.Services.Replace(typeof(IHttpControllerSelector), new NamespaceHttpControllerSelector(config));

        config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver =
            new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();

        config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/html"));

        if (enableDiagnostics)
            EnableSystemDiagnosticTracing(config);

        ConfigureCors(config);

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }

    private static void ConfigureCors(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        var origins = new string[]
        {
            "http://localhost:20936",
            "http://msft-web-dev1:93"
        };

        var corsAttribute = new EnableCorsAttribute(
            string.Join(",", origins),
            "Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, X-Requested-With",
            "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS");

        corsAttribute.SupportsCredentials = true;
        config.EnableCors(corsAttribute);
    }
```

I have also tried using * wildcards for the methods and verbs.  Here is the response headers for the pre-flighted OPTIONS request:

- HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
- Content-Type: text/html
- Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
- WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate
- WWW-Authenticate: NTLM
- X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
- Date: Thu, 17 Dec 2015 16:33:57 GMT
- Content-Length: 1293

You will notice that it's not writing out the appropriate headers necessary to pass the preflight.

And the request headers:

- Accept:*/*
- Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch
- Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
- Access-Control-Request-Headers:content-type
- Access-Control-Request-Method:POST
- Cache-Control:no-cache
- Connection:keep-alive
- Host:msft-web-dev1:93
- Origin:http://localhost:20936
- Pragma:no-cache
- Referer:http://localhost:20936/
  User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.80 Safari/537.36

I don't have anything specific in my web.config regarding auth except the following:

```
<system.webServer>
<handlers>
  <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
  <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
  <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
  <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
</handlers>
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
  <add name="ErrorLog" type="Elmah.ErrorLogModule, Elmah" />
</modules>
</system.webServer>
```

I have found a way to make this work in the global.aspx.cs file:

```
        protected void Application_EndRequest()
    {
        if (Context.Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
        {
            Context.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:20936");
            Context.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
            Context.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type");
            Context.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "PUT, DELETE");
            Context.Response.StatusCode = 200;
        }
    }
```

When I do it this way, here's the response from my OPTIONS request:

- Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true
- Access-Control-Allow-Headers:Content-Type
- Access-Control-Allow-Methods: PUT, DELETE
- Access-Control-Allow-Origin:http://localhost:20936

I'm not totally against going this route, but isn't the point of EnableCors to avoid this and give the ability to this either globally, per controller, or per route?

Also the API is hosted on IIS (Windows Server 2012) and it's using Windows Auth and every other scheme including anonymous is disabled.

Really stumped here.

Comment: there are two cos: web-api and owin, make sure you have enabled both

Comment: entre - can you be more specific?  I'm not using OWIN middleware.  Is that still a requirement?